# Identifying element for iOS using classname on Appium Inspector

Tags: appium, classname, inspector

There is a button on the screen, which I am trying to identify as iOS element using classname on Appium Inspector. But I keep getting the error "element cannot be found".

This is the button which I wanted to identify.

```
 <UIAButton name="Join Us" label="Join Us" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/2/9" x="0" y="483" width="320" height="48"> </UIAButton>
```

I am using the command UIAButton[@name='Join Us'] by selecting the Strategy dropdown as "classname" on Appium Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you should be using for that query is Xpath. You'll also need the leading "//" (ex: `//UIAButton[@name='Join Us']`). If you want to use the class strategy, the class would be UIAButton, but I'm not sure how you would specify "Join Us" after that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, unfortunately, there is a problem with Instruments in using xcode, so I am trying to identify element in a different way.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [iOS UIAutomator](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?csharp#ios-predicate) strategy, then. It is much faster and more reliable than Xcode.